# Using a method within a class as an operator to assign a value to private member of the class

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, private-members

Folks, I am trying to use a method within a class to assign a value to a private member of that class. I can't figure this out to save my hind-parts. Can anyone please point out the obvious?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
class NoClass {
    public:
        NoClass() { };
        NoClass(const NoClass& orig) { };
        virtual ~NoClass() { };
        void SetAnInt() {
            this->anInt = ???;
        }
        int GetAnInt() {
            return this->anInt;
        }
    private:
        int anInt;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    NoClass *nc = new NoClass();
    nc->SetAnInt() = 133; // Important part here
    printf("%d\n", nc->GetAnInt());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, you can do this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
class NoClass {
    public:
        NoClass() { };
        NoClass(const NoClass& orig) { };
        virtual ~NoClass() { };

        int& SetAnInt() {
            return anInt;
        }

        int GetAnInt() {
            return this->anInt;
        }
    private:
        int anInt;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    NoClass *nc = new NoClass();
    nc->SetAnInt() = 133; // Important part here
    printf("%d\n", nc->GetAnInt());
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this exploits the language to overcome data hiding, which is one of the cornerstones of object-oriented programming. It's bad. Like, really, really bad. So, don't do it. But, you can. And I'd love to hear what your professor says about it.

Also, extraneous `this->` harms code readability, and this isn't java.

Comment: Niggle: Since `SetAnInt` does double duty as a setter and a getter by returning an lvalue, I'd remove the getter and give `SetAnInt` a more descriptive name.

Comment: @NonSequitur whoever assigned this. If you’re working through a tutorial, it’ll have an answer, and this will never come up in an actual work project, thus I assume it’s homework. And given that you’ve overridden the copy constructor for no reason, and prevented it from actually *copying*... there are a ton of things wrong with this code, so I was being optimistic and assuming you’re taking a course.

Comment: Dav3: Can you provide a code example of your proposed solution to such a problem? Please?

Comment: @NonSequitur not here to do you’re homework for you. If you’re learning the language on your own: kudos! And post another question with whatever the specific problem is. I and others will do what we can to help.

Comment: It's always problematic to jump to conclusions. That being said, various organizations have reason for the various programming techniques they use, and the question posted on the forum may not exactly highlight those requirements. And that being said, I appreciate the help; I reviewed some of the older revisions of the code and found one reason why this wasn't working. Owe that lightbulb going on to you folks. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in the value that you want to set to as a argument.

```
void SetAnInt(int val) {
    this->anInt = val;
     //or just
    //anInt = val
    }
```

Then, you can call it in main like

```
 nc->SetAnInt(133);
```

Alternatively, to be able to write

```
nc->SetAnInt() = 133;
```

you will need to make `SetAnInt()` return a reference to the data member `anInt`

```
int& SetAnInt() {
    return anInt;
}
```